# Can I change industry output when creating an OpenTTD scenario?

Tags: openttd

I'm building a small scenario for practicing rail networks, junctions, stations etc. So far I have 4 large cities which is great for high-volume passenger traffic, bus transfers and the basics.

Now I add some industry - primary / natural resource only because the player can easily afford to build secondary in the gaps - but their performance is random and usually low.

I can't find any settings in the scenario editor to change industry properties. Can I configure their output?

Answer (score 3):

You can use the hotkey ctrl+alt+c. This opens the cheat window. 
This option is only possible in singleplayer.

Comment: Surprisingly enough this actually works. You can't fine tune the amount, but you can adjust it broadly (seems each button press would half or double the production)